# variables not posting php form

Tags: php, forms, post, get

So I'm working on this password reset form. Where a user clicks on a link sent to their email and they are taken to a webpage to enter a new password. When they submit the form 3 variables (password, key, & email) are passed to my functions file to update the password for the user. The password itself is being posted, but the email and key are not. I did a vardump to see what is actually being sent and its just displaying the code in the values of email/key on the form. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**
So I figured out that the email/key were not being passed to the updateUserPassword() function. I posted the new correct form code below. **SOLVED**

```
     <?php session_start();
include("include/DB_Connect.php"); 
    include("include/DB_Functions.php"); // Connect to database server(localhost) with username and password.  
    mysql_select_db("android_api") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database. 
$show = 'emailForm'; //which form step to show by default
if (isset($_POST['subStep']) && !isset($_GET['a']))
{
    switch($_POST['subStep'])
    {
        case 1:
            //we are submitting a new password (only for encrypted)
        if ($_POST['email'] == '' || $_POST['key'] == '') header("location: forgotpw.php");
        if (strcmp($_POST['password'],$_POST['pw1']) != 0 || trim($_POST['password']) == '')
        {
            $error = true;
            $show = 'recoverForm';
        } else {
            $error = false;
            $show = 'recoverSuccess';
            updateUserPassword($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['key']);
            var_dump($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['key']);
        }
        break;
    }
} elseif (isset($_GET['a']) && $_GET['a'] == 'recover' && $_GET['email'] != "") {
    $show = 'invalidKey';
    $result = checkEmailKey(urldecode(base64_decode($_GET['email'])),$_GET['key']);
    if ($result == false)
    {
        $error = true;
        $show = 'invalidKey';
    } elseif ($result['status'] == true) {
        $error = false;
        $show = 'recoverForm';
        $securityUser = $result['email'];
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Password Recovery</title>
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="page">
        <?php switch($show) {
            case 'recoverForm': ?>
            <h2>Password Recovery</h2>
            <p>Welcome back, <?php echo getUserName($securityUser=='' ? $_GET['email'] : $securityUser); ?>.</p>
            <p>In the fields below, enter your new password.</p>
            <?php if ($error == true) { ?><span class="error">The new passwords must match and must not be empty.</span><?php } ?>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                <div class="fieldGroup"><label for="password">New Password</label><div class="field"><input type="password" class="input" name="password" id="password" value="" maxlength="20"></div></div>
                <div class="fieldGroup"><label for="pw1">Confirm Password</label><div class="field"><input type="password" class="input" name="pw1" id="pw1" value="" maxlength="20"></div></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="subStep" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $securityUser=='' ? $_POST['email'] : $securityUser; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $_GET['key']=='' ? $_POST['key'] : $_GET['key']; ?>" />
                <div class="fieldGroup"><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 150px;" /></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </form>
            <?php break; case 'invalidKey': ?>
            <h2>Invalid Key</h2>
            <p>The key that you entered was invalid. Either you did not copy the entire key from the email, you are trying to use the key after it has expired (3 days after request), or you have already used the key in which case it is deactivated.<br /><br /><a href="login.php">Return</a> to the login page. </p>
            <?php break; case 'recoverSuccess': ?>
            <h2>Password Reset</h2>
            <p>Congratulations! your password has been reset successfully.</p><br /><br /><a href="login.php">Return</a> to the login page. </p>    
            <?php break; }
            ob_flush();
            $mySQL->close();
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my function code:

```
    function updateUserPassword($email,$password,$key)
{
    global $mySQL;
    if (checkEmailKey($email,$key) === false) return false;
    if ($SQL = $mySQL->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` = ? WHERE `email` = ?"))
    {
        $password = md5(trim($password) . PW_SALT);
        $SQL->bind_param('ss',$email,$password);
        $SQL->execute();
        $SQL->close();
        $SQL = $mySQL->prepare("DELETE FROM `recoveryemails_enc` WHERE `Key` = ?");
        $SQL->bind_param('s',$key);
        $SQL->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the values are passed through correctly (like you tested) there's probably something wrong in the code for `updateUserPassword()`

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with my function. I posted the function code in my OP.

Comment: This calls for more debugging. It's something even the most experienced programmers have to do frequently. What goes wrong where? At which point are you losing data?

Comment: I don't know where I'm losing data. I ran the queries manually in mysql to make sure they were ok and they were. I don't know alot about debugging sql functions though.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, consider using MySQLi. mysql_* functions have been officially deprecated